Cannot install llama-index-embeddings-huggingface==0.1.3 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies
I am unable to install the huggingfaceEmbedding \
Getting the followng error:
ERROR: Cannot install llama-index-embeddings-huggingface==0.1.3, llama-index-embeddings-huggingface==0.1.4 and llama-index-embeddings-huggingface==0.1.5 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.
ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts

Python version: 3.13



Several things I had to do in order to make this work.

Downgrade to python 3.9.  I went specifically to 3.9.13.  Without that some of your imports in code will not work as well.
Use a virtual environment.  I can't tell if you have done this.  It may not be necessary but it worked for me.
Use uv to install packages.  It seems to sort out the dependencies a bit easier than straight pip.  uv can be installed via pip install uv.  Then uv pip instal 

This got the llama_index_embedded_huggingface package to install.
